# How to create Business rule engine in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mongodb, postgres, business-rules, elasticsearch, rules-engine

Our organization is into Health Care RCM business. In that, we use to receive medical records (called as accounts, which is a business phrase) and our staff (Medical coders) use to do medical coding, based on the accounts received.

On daily basis, accounts will be receiving in a high volume from multiple clients and they will be pushed into inventory table. The accounts will be assigned to the coders based on the business rules created in our application.

Based on business need any rule can be created by business people. There could be hundreds of rules executed before an account is assigned to the coder. Currently, this is handled in Postgres table by the storing the rules in a table as a "WHERE" clause. Please find some example rules below.

1. Highly complex accounts should be allocated to experienced coders

**Rule Condition:** WHERE c.cpt_code = '00100' and e.experience_type = 'experienced'

2. Accounts with high dollar claims should be completed on high priority

**Rule Condition:** WHERE claim_amount > 5000

3. Accounts about the expire has be completed on urgent basis

**Rule Condition:** WHERE expiry_date = NOW()

4. Staff "john.mathew" has to be assigned with the accounts arrived from "Dallas"

**Rule Condition:** WHERE u.staffname = 'john.mathew' and l.location = 'Dallas'

When the coder hits the "Fetch Account" button, the rules applicable to the respective coder will be executed (against the accounts' inventory) and an account will be assigned to the coder when an account satisfies a rule condition.

But, we are facing lot of performance issues due to the above architecture, as the rules are executed multiple times against inventory.

To get rid of this, we are planning to rearchitect this by developing a stand-alone rule engine, which should be loosely coupled with our core application, but it should meet the below criterias.

1. High performance
2. Highly configurable
3. Easily pluggable with RDBMS(Postgres)

Our Technology stack is,

Application Platform: .Net core 6.0

Database: Postgres

If developing an in-house tool is the best option, then can we develop it with any of the following tech stack MongoDB, ElasticSearch or any tools readily available that suits our requirement

Comment: Such a good description at the beginning, just ending with a 100% off-topic tool recommendation request. But before I vote to close this, let me add a comment: I don't think adding a MongoDB or ElasticSearch is likely bringing you any benefit. These are tools better suited for high-traffic websites with thousands of users, with document-oriented data and/or full-text search requirements. If you develop a stand-alone rule engine, why not try ot with the database your team already knows well?

Comment: ...  I would expect the database itself unlikely to be the real bottleneck, it is more your current usage pattern which has to be optimized. Using Postgresql here for the rule engine itself will solve your requirement #3 immediately.

Comment: But before you go that route: did you try cache the results from older "Fetch Accounts" runs, and store and reuse them as long as no rule changes? Maybe you can cache some intermediate results? Maybe you can distinguish between rule changes which only reduce the (formerly cached) resultset, and others, which require to invalidate the cache?

Comment: As you said, hopefully, we will end up with the Postgresql only, and not jumping to any document database.

Comment: Will consider your suggestion to cache the resultset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do might be to shift the heavy lifting part of rule execution (evaluating all the business rules in order) from the `SELECT` phase to the `INSERT` phase when accounts (which apparently correspond to "tickets" in general workflow parlance) are inserted into your system, so it is performed only once per account created. You may need to translate the existing rules from SQL into some domain specific language that can be evaluated efficiently in the application that imports accounts from the clients.

Rules would assign tags and/or numerical attributes such as priority to the accounts, and the account/coder matching algorithm would only perform simple and fixed SQL statements which can be executed efficiently by the database engine.

Comment: thanks for your inputs. We have discussed the same option what you suggested, but the business rules might be updated frequently. Each time a rule created/modified, all the accounts has to be updated appropriately, which may become tedious which is the reason why we have kept this option on-hold. This should be the last resort. Note: Yes, we do have rule priorities.

Comment: How often is "frequently"? It might still be ok to update all open accounts (those not yet assigned to a coder) when a business rule is changed or created if that doesn't happen for hundreds of rules per day. If rules are updated so frequently, one might ask whether real-time updating is actually needed, it might be sufficient to do it twice daily.

Comment: The rules that are evaluated when a record is inserted or updated could be  executed by a trigger (after insert, after update) using a copy of the record in a temporary table.

Comment: May be we can't specify the frequency as it is completely depends on business criticality. Say for a scenario, if some claims from a particular location has to be completed on priority, a new rule will be created instantly. Roughly saying, rules may be updated for every one hour. However, as you said, we can enforce the business people to update the rules at a particular interval(once in 3 hours)

Comment: If you have to query the entire DB to evaluate new rules very often rather than changing database you might want to try to shard it.

Comment: Yes. Sharding is already in place. As we are in Health care business, data isolation is very crucial. Separate databases for each client.